# ASP.Net MVC choose DropDownList/TextBox for editing depending on which one is visible

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following code in my cshtml for creating a new database entry:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHideAds(button) {
    var dAds = document.getElementById("dAds");

    if (dAds.style.display == "none") {
        dAds.style.display = "block"
    }
    else {
        dAds.style.display = "none"
    }
    if (lstAds.style.display == "none") {
        lstAds.style.display = "block"
    }
    else {
        lstAds.style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById('dAds').value = document.getElementById('lstAds').value;
    }
}
function ShowHideRg(button) {
    var dRg = document.getElementById("dRg");
    if (dRg.style.display == "none"){
        dRg.style.display = "block"
    }
    else{
        dRg.style.display = "none"
    }
    if (lstRg.style.display == "none") {
        lstRg.style.display = "block"
    }
    else {
        lstRg.style.display = "none"
    }
}
</script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Entry</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ADSName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div id="lstAds" display="block">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ADSName, ViewBag.adsName as SelectList, "Choose Name")
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="ShowHideAds(this)" style="text-align: left; color: #F6855E; background: none;
                                                                                margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;
                                                                                border: none; cursor: pointer;" />
        </div>
        <div id="dAds" style="display: none;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADSName)
            <input type="button" value="x" onclick="ShowHideAds(this)" style="text-align: left; color: #F6855E; background: none;
                                                                                margin: 0; padding: 0;  padding-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;
                                                                                border: none; cursor: pointer;" />
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADSName)
    </div>  }
```

and my two Create methods in my Controller class:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<RightStructure> rightList = entities.RightStructure.ToList();

        SelectList listAds = new SelectList(rightList.Select(x => x.ADSName).Distinct(), "ADSName");
        ViewBag.adsName = listAds;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RightStructure rights)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            entities.RightStructure .Add(rights);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(rechte);
    }
```

Now, on a button click I can either make the DropDownList disappear, causing the TextBox to appear or vice versa.
What I want is to take only the value of the current visible Control to create a new entry in my database. Unfortunally, only the DropDownList value is always being caught into my RightStructure object. So that means - if the DropDownList is visible -> take the selected value. If the Textbox is visible -> take the entered value. 
I tried to realize this over the script function above but could not get it to work. Also I could not find something when searching the Internet. Could somebody help?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You are trying to bind a value 2 times for one property. try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53615862/4799441) answer. It would solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this to my code. I'm hiding them already and both are Textinput. Could you post an example? That would be nice

Comment: @Canox Have you tried giving a unique `id` to your form controls: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADSName,new {@id = "adsnamebox"})` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ADSName, ViewBag.adsName as SelectList, "Choose Name",new {@id="adsdropdown"})`. Then try to get their values in your javascript and see what you get in your `Controller` method.

Comment: Where should I pass the ids? But not in the function? Sry when I'm asking. I developed in C# and this is my first time using ASP ord javascript/css. Still learning.

Comment: @Canox You do not need to pass the id's as such to your function. You can retrieve your values using `Jquery`: `var adsnameboxvalue= $("#adsnamebox").val();` or `Javascript`:`document.getElementById('adsnamebox').value;`

Comment: Ok. How do I pass them to the controller? Problem here is that only the dropdown value gets passed. the textbox value simply gets ignored. So I have to tell which value to choose from both somehow. or maybe do an if else in razor.

Comment: @Canox Ahh I see, you have two options here. 1) You can use a strongly typed Model in your Form and let the framework do the binding to your `Controller` method. 2) You can use `Jquery` or `Javascript` to capture your required values and send them to your `Controller` via `AJAX`. In your case, it seems that you are using a mix of the two. I would suggest you go for the `JQuery` option since you have some change in values based on an event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to Rahul Sharma and JayNaz.

I found a solution, but I still need one step.

Instead of DropDownListFor and TextBoxFor I used DropDownList and TextBox:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ADSlist", ViewBag.adsName as SelectList, "Choose Name")
@Html.TextBox("ADSTxt")
```

So now in my Controller I can do this:

```
var value = Request["ADSList"];
var value2 = Request["ADSTxt"];
```

Now I only need to know which Control is currently visible. Does someone know how to achieve that?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Got it. Just added the following in my functions:

```
        var txtBox = "Hidden";
        $.post("/Rights/GetState", { txtAds: txtBox });
```

...and "Visible" when the Textbox is visible. So now I also added a new method in my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetState(string txtAds, string txtRg)
    {
        stateTxtAds = txtAds;
        stateTxtRg = txtRg;
        return View();
    }
```

so I can set the global variables stateTxtAds and stateTxtRg and use them in my Create Method.